# Print data in javascript from json

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to print json policyUrl from every record in javascript and I mean **policyUrl**. if i try to print it console live server its work corectly but if I try to clg it in by loop its not working
Here is all data . https://github.com/neqts/jsonData
Help...

```js
"use strict"




console.log(json)

const getNames = (obj) => Object.values(obj).map(el => el.name)

const purposesNames =getNames(json.purposes)
const vendorsNames = getNames(json.vendors)
const specialFeaturesNames =getNames(json.specialFeatures)
const specialPurposesNames = getNames(json.specialPurposes)
const stacksNames = getNames(json.stacks)


console.log(purposesNames,vendorsNames,specialFeaturesNames,specialPurposesNames,stacksNames)


var step;
for (step = 0; step < 972; step++) {
 console.log(json.vendors[step].policyUrl)  
 
}

 console.log(json.vendors[1].policyUrl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `script.js` replace your loop with the following:

```js
Object.entries(json.vendors).forEach(vendor => console.log(vendor[1].policyUrl))
```

Your script is not working since `json.vendors` is not an array. You can change your json data to an array solution or you have to parse the data with Object.entries to an array.

Comment: I use json with padding https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP its not mistake

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: Bay the way if i want to add it in innerHtml how its would look like?

Answer (score 1):

for innerHTML, here is the updated script. let me know..

```
"use strict"

console.log(json)
const getNames = (obj) => Object.values(obj).map(el => el.name)

const purposesNames = getNames(json.purposes)
const vendorsNames = getNames(json.vendors)
const specialFeaturesNames = getNames(json.specialFeatures)
const specialPurposesNames = getNames(json.specialPurposes)
const stacksNames = getNames(json.stacks)
let outputArr = []
window.onload = function main() {
  const add = document.createElement('div')
  add.setAttribute("id", "demo");

  const overall = document.createElement('div')
  Object.entries(json.vendors).forEach(vendor => {
    outputArr.push(vendor[1].policyUrl) + "<br>"
  })
  //console.log(outputArr)
  overall.style.cssText = `
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1000;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    `;
  add.style.cssText = `
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 300px;
      height: 400px;
      background: white;
      margin-left:150px
    `;
  add.textContent = "GDPR consent"
  overall.appendChild(add);
  //document.body.style.overflow="hidden"
  document.body.appendChild(add);
  //document.body.style.background = "url(https://www.hgsm.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Pattern-Blue-Dots-background-patterns-pattern-wallpapers-1920x1080.jpg)"
  var final = document.getElementById("demo");
  final.innerHTML = outputArr.join('<br>');
}
```